# How are methods, `classmethod`, and `staticmethod` implemented in Python?

Tags: python, class, methods, built-in

At what point do methods in Python acquire a `get` property?  —As soon as they're defined in the class?  Why does Python let me define a method without any arguments (not even a first `self` argument)?

I know how to use `classmethod` and `staticmethod`, and I know that they're built-in functions, but what happens to a function that is so-decorated?

Essentially, I'm wondering about the "magic" that happens between class definition and class construction.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Check this out.

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#class-methods

You can also take a look at the source code for class and static method objects, in funcobject.c:

http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/69b416cd1727/Objects/funcobject.c

Class method object definition starts on line 694, while static method object definition starts on line 852. (I do find it kind of funny that they have items titled "method" in funcobject.c when methodobject.c also exists.)

Comment: The #reference on that link is now 404 so you may want to follow: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#class-methods instead

Comment: I would really appreciate an explanation and walk-through here of the `class ClassMethod:` implementation of `"Emulate PyClassMethod_Type() in Objects/funcobject.c"` found at https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#class-methods

Comment: @NeilG Thanks for the heads up. What particularly are you confused about with the pure Python version?

Comment: I asked this question 12 years ago, can't even remember asking it, and criticise it as it seems self-contradictory. I was just reviewing non-data descriptor protocol, function objects, and method implementation, which I'm sure I haven't fully grasped yet, but I was only commenting as a *correction*, not from confusion. But that was 3 weeks ago and I haven't got time to go back into it now, but I think the piece that's missing from most explanations is how methods are *called* under the hood, given that `__get__` is called with `obj` and `objtype=None` in addition to the function object `self`.

Comment: @NeilG Basically, `types.FunctionType.__get__` is defined to implement instance methods. `classmethod` and `staticmethod` just provide suitable definitions of `__get__` to implement class- and static-method behavior, respectively. (For example, `staticmethod.__get__` always returns the underlying function instead of a `method` object.)

Comment: Thanks @chepner - I'm a lot clearer now on this and since the question was asked Python has changed the underlying process, but that's a good way of thinking about it. The funny thing that I just realised though, is that the "Neil G" who asked the question is not me! No wonder I couldn't remember asking the question! Lol :-D

Answer (score 14):

For reference, from [the first link](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html#static-methods-and-class-methods) in @JAB's answer

> Using the non-data descriptor protocol, a pure Python version of staticmethod() would look like this:
>
> ```py
> class StaticMethod(object):
>     "Emulate PyStaticMethod_Type() in Objects/funcobject.c"
>
>     def __init__(self, f):
>         self.f = f
>
>     def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
>         return self.f
> ```

...

> Using the non-data descriptor protocol, a pure Python version of classmethod() would look like this:
>
> ```py
> class ClassMethod(object):
>     "Emulate PyClassMethod_Type() in Objects/funcobject.c"
>
>     def __init__(self, f):
>         self.f = f
>
>     def __get__(self, obj, klass=None):
>         if klass is None:
>             klass = type(obj)
>         def newfunc(*args):
>             return self.f(klass, *args)
>         return newfunc
> ```