# 'staticmethod' object is not callable

Tags: python

I have this code:

```py
class A(object):
    @staticmethod
    def open():
        return 123

    @staticmethod
    def proccess():
        return 456

    switch = {
        1: open,
        2: proccess,
    }


obj = A.switch[1]()
```

When I run this I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable
```

how to resolve it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798835/understanding-get-and-set-and-python-descriptors

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['classmethod' object is not callable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058686/classmethod-object-is-not-callable)

Comment: @melpomene: oops, I'm not sure why I missed that.

Comment: @melpomene: not entirely a dupe, you have different (more) options with `staticmethod` objects.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, I didn't quite realize that the question title doesn't match the error message in the body.

Comment: @melpomene: indeed, I got it wrong initially too, but then forgot to edit the question title.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You are storing *unbound* `staticmethod` objects in a dictionary. Such objects (as well as `classmethod` objects, functions and `property` objects)  are only bound through the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), by accessing the name as an attribute on the class or an instance. Directly accessing the `staticmethod` objects in the class body is not an attribute access.

Either create the dictionary *after* creating the class (so you access them as attributes), or bind explicitly, or extract the original function before storing them in the dictionary.

Note that 'binding' for `staticmethod` objects merely means that the context is merely ignored; a bound `staticmethod` returns the underlying function unchanged.

So your options are to unindent the dictionary and trigger the descriptor protocol by using attributes:

```
class A(object):
    @staticmethod
    def open():
        return 123
    @staticmethod
    def proccess():
        return 456

A.switch = {
    1: A.open,
    2: A.proccess,   
}
```

or to bind explicitly, passing in a dummy context (which will be ignored anyway):

```
class A(object):
    @staticmethod
    def open():
        return 123
    @staticmethod
    def proccess():
        return 456

    switch = {
        1: open.__get__(object),
        2: proccess.__get__(object),   
    }
```

or access the underlying function directly with the `__func__` attribute:

```
class A(object):
    @staticmethod
    def open():
        return 123
    @staticmethod
    def proccess():
        return 456

    switch = {
        1: open.__func__,
        2: proccess.__func__,   
    }
```

However, if all you are trying to do is provide a *namespace* for a bunch of functions, then you should not use a class object in the first place. Put the functions in a *module*. That way you don't have to use `staticmethod` decorators in the first place and don't have to unwrap them again.

Comment: The note at the end is the most important part, IMO. We can just create a list of all the functions we want from a module, and call them in a loop.

Comment: Both ```open.__func__``` and ```open.__get__(object)``` get PyCharm warnings, though work. ```open.__get__(object, None)``` gets no warnings and works too

Comment: @SergeyNudnov: I suspect PyCharm would be happier about `open.__func__` if you used a type guard like `inspect.ismethod()` on it first. That PyCharm complains about `open.__get__(object)` sounds like a bug, the `__get__` descriptor protocol method is [is documented to take a default value for the owner argument](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__).

Answer (score 9):

Note that starting with Python 3.10 the workarounds given in the accepted answer are no longer needed (but still work):

> Moreover, static methods are now callable as regular functions.
> (Contributed by Victor Stinner in bpo-43682.)

For more details see: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html

```
Python 3.10.2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class A():
...     @staticmethod
...     def open():
...         return 123
...     @staticmethod
...     def process():
...         return 456
...     switch = {
...         1: open,
...         2: process
...     }
...
>>> A.switch[1]()
123
```

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Pieters' answer, you can just drop `@staticmethod`:

```py
class A(object):
    def open():
        return 123

    def proccess():
        return 456

    switch = {
        1: open,
        2: proccess,   
        }

obj = A.switch[1]()
```

However, in this way it becomes impossible to call `open` and `process` with `self`.

- Outside the class they can be called either with `A.open()` and `A.process()`, just like common static methods.
- Inside the class they can be called with just  `open()` and `process()`, without `A.`. However,

  - `A.open` will fail.  (I tested this case only with the decorator use. (`@open`))
  - What's more, they must be placed before the function calling them.

Comment: With this being possible why is @staticmethod decorator even included in python?

Comment: @Rhdr I think `@staticmethod` makes it possible to access static methods with `self.`, `self.__dict__` and `self.__getattribute__`, consistent with common dynamic methods. (I haven't tried `__dict__`/`__getattribute__`, but they should work) (See the implementation of `@staticmethod` at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60383279/8535456)

Answer (score 2):

```
class A(object):
    def open():
        return 123

    def proccess():
        return 456

    switch = {
        1: lambda : A.open(),
        2: lambda : A.proccess(),   
        }
```

Comment: Adding an explanation or a short note for how/what your code fixes the issue is a good idea!

Comment: Interesting approach, but if there are any parameters to the methods, there will be much more code there

Answer (score 2):

### For Unit Tests

Thanks to and based on [**Martijn** answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41921291/6225838), both `__func__` and `__get__(TestCase)` options work well when using static methods on tests, example:

```
from unittest import TestCase, mock
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, Mock
class TestMother(TestCase):

    @staticmethod
    def side_effect_me(param: str) -> str:
        return param.capitalize()
    
    @mock.patch("src.some_folder.MyModule.my_func", \
        new=MagicMock(side_effect=side_effect_me.__func__))
    def test_should_cap(self):
        # test stuff
```