# Why do I get ''staticmethod' object is not callable' when I try to get the method?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, static-methods, python-object

I try to give the user the possibility to choose which function to use for a class.

### Snippet 1

Something like this:

```
class TestFoo():

    @staticmethod
    def foo(x, y):
        return x * y

    methodstr2method = {'foo': foo}

    def __init__(self, method_str):
        self.method = self.methodstr2method[method_str]

    def exec(self, x, y):
        return self.method(x, y)


a = TestFoo('foo')
print(a.exec(3, 7))
```

However, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/math/Desktop/foobar.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(a.exec(3, 7))
  File "/home/math/Desktop/foobar.py", line 13, in exec
    return self.method(x, y)
TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable
```

When I remove the `@staticmethod`, it works. Why is that the case? I thought without the decorator, the first argument would always be `self` or `cls`?
**Why doesn't snippet 1 work?**

### Snippet 2

This one, however, works:

```
class TestFoo():

    @staticmethod
    def foo(x, y):
        return x * y


    def __init__(self, method_str):
        self.methodstr2method = {'foo': self.foo}
        self.method = self.methodstr2method[method_str]

    def exec(self, x, y):
        return self.method(x, y)


a = TestFoo('foo')
print(a.exec(3, 7))
```

Comment: Might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41921255/staticmethod-object-is-not-callable-switch-case

Comment: Add a `foo.__func__` as per the other answer.

Comment: For **Snippet 1**, `foo()` is not a static method. Just remove `@staticmethod` decorator from `foo()` and run again. You'll get 21 as a output.