# Puzzle with staticmethod in a class variable I can't figure out

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a class static method, and then use it in a class variable as a callback.  I'm running into a problem with the static method not being callable that I can't figure out:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Callable

@dataclass
class Option:
    txt: str
    callback: Callable

class Window:

    @staticmethod
    def _doit(a=1):
        print('do it with a', a)

    cvar = Option(txt='doit', callback=_doit)


w1 = Window()

w1._doit()
# works fine
Window._doit()
# works fine
w1.cvar.callback()
# this fails
```

The last call above fails with `"TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable"`.

I'm not sure why here, *but even more confusing to me is if I remove the `@staticmethod` line, then things work 'correctly'* - with all 3 calls in the code working.

I know I must being doing something stupid wrong, but I can't figure out what's wrong with the above ...any help?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Oops, @Richard correctly pointed out that my original example was broken - I did not see the error since I had already defined the `Window` class running the original code.  A bit tricky, but here is a version that should work along with a more detailed [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718187/calling-class-staticmethod-within-the-class-body).

EDIT #2: Sigh, fixed another typo. :^(

Example:

```
cvar = Option(txt='doit', callback=_doit.__func__)
```

Comment: Thanks - that was my first thought, which I tried.   ...but that fails, with `name 'Window' is not defined`.

Comment: ...thanks! ...note you need to edit your answer to remove the () after __func__ ...otherwise it will execute the function, not point to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment above, I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41921291/9423009) previous answer to similar question.

To correct the code above - where you're trying to reference a static method before it's bound - you need to reference the function location directly:

```py
class Window:

    @staticmethod
    def _doit(a=1):
        print('do it with a', a)

    cvar = Option(txt='doit', callback=_doit.__func__)
```

The other option (which I'd already found worked, but preferred to identify my function explicitly as a staticmethod, was to remove the staticmethod decorator.