# How to, if possible, "unbound" bounded method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that I can't modify as it's a 3rd party, lets say it's an `add` function.

```
def add(a, b):
    print(a + b)
```

For this example lets call it in init. It has to be assigned to the class as a class variable. That way it will automatically become a bounded method. In order to prevent "bounding" I need to decorate it with a `staticmethod`.

```
class Base:
    func: Callable

    def __init__(self):
        self.func(a=1, b=2)


class Working(Base):
    func = staticmethod(add)
```

And it is working fine as that way `self` is not passed to the function.

I was wondering if it's possible to "unbound" / make it static in init

```
class NotWorking(Base):
    func = add

    def __init__(self):
        staticmethod(self.func)(a=1, b=2)
```

It has to be reusable from the `Base` class so I don't need to rewrite the same thing over and over.

```
class NotWorking2(Base):
    func = subtract
```

It's not something I need, I was just wondering if it's possible to "unbound" it once it was bounded.

In `Working` class it's just a function

```
<function add at 0x7f1be89de1f0>
```

but in `NotWorking` it's either

```
<bound method add of <__main__.NotWorking object at 0x7f0ed11e47f0>>
```

or a `staticmethod` which results in

```
TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable
```

I have seen ['staticmethod' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41921255/staticmethod-object-is-not-callable) but it doesn't really answer my question.

I don't think it's possible but is there a cleaner way so the `staticmethod` can be called only once if I have plenty of such classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to simply not call it as a method on `self`:

```
class Base:
    func: typing.ClassVar[Callable]

    def __init__(self):
        type(self).func(a=1, b=2)

class NowWorking(Base):
    func = add
```

---

Original answer:

```
class NowWorking(Base):
    func = add

    def __init__(self):
        NowWorking.func(a=1, b=2)
```

Comment: The problem is I have a lot of classes like that and the idea is not to do anything in `init` but rather add it in the interface / abstractclass - here, `Base`.

Comment: You could also call `type(self).func`, which is more flexible I suppose.

Comment: By the way, I think the type of `Base.func` should be `typing.ClassVar[Callable]`.

Comment: `func = type(self).func` did the trick. Thank you! And you're right on the type. Will accept in 3 min.

Comment: Glad to hear it! I didn't make that my initial answer because I thought there was an edge-case w/ subclassing but I tried it out and it worked just fine.