# Stuck on figuring out the logic for conditional IF ELSE statement

Tags: python, json, config

I have my code here that reads my config file:

```
def getConfig(env):
    pwd=os.getcwd()
    if "win" in (platform.system().lower()):
        f = open(pwd+"\config_"+env.lower()+"_dataset2.json")
    else:
        f = open(pwd+"/config_"+env.lower()+"_dataset2.json")
    config = json.load(f)
    f.close()
    return config
```

The thing is, I want it to read my other config file as well but I don't know how to incorporate it in the original code above. I know something like this won't work:

```
def getConfig(env):
    pwd=os.getcwd()
    if "win" in (platform.system().lower()):
        f = open(pwd+"\config_"+env.lower()+"_dataset2.json")
    else:
        f = open(pwd+"/config_"+env.lower()+"_dataset2.json")
    if "win" in (platform.system().lower()):
        f = open(pwd+"\config_"+env.lower()+"_dataset1.json")
    else:
        f = open(pwd+"/config_"+env.lower()+"_dataset1.json")
    config = json.load(f)
    f.close()
    return config
```

I'm stuck on having the option to run both config files at once, or just run dataset1.json individually, or just run dataset2.json individually.

Maybe something like:

```
dataset2=config_"+env.lower()+"_dataset2.json
dataset1=config_"+env.lower()+"_dataset1.json

if dataset2:
          f = open(pwd+"\config_"+env.lower()+"_dataset2.json")....


@staticmethod
def getConfig(env):
    pwd=os.getcwd()
    env = env.lower()

    with open(os.path.join(pwd, f"config_{env}_dataset2.json")) as f:
        config2 = json.load(f)
    with open(os.path.join(pwd, f"config_{env}_dataset1.json")) as f:
        config1 = json.load(f)

    return config2, config1

config2, config1 = getConfig(env)

TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable
```

Comment: You should use a raw string if the string contains a literal backslash.

Comment: But why do you need to do this? Windows allow you to use `/` as the directory separator. You can also use `pathlib` and let it deal with the OS dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

You can return multiple values from the function.

There's no need for the conditionals, use `os.path.join()` to combine pathnames with the OS-specific delimiter.

```
def getConfig(env):
    pwd=os.getcwd()
    env = env.lower()

    with open(os.path.join(pwd, f"config_{env}_dataset2.json")) as f:
        config1 = json.load(f)
    with open(os.path.join(pwd, f"config_{env}_dataset1.json")) as f:
        config2 = json.load(f)

    return config1, config2

dataset1, dataset2 = getConfig(env)
```

You also don't really need to join with `pwd`, since relative pathnames are interpreted relative to the current directory.

Comment: thanks for the response. i have tried your code and it doesn't work because (i forgot to include) @staticmethod above my original function. it returns the error:

TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41921255/staticmethod-object-is-not-callable

Comment: hmm im a little confused because im not storing anything in a dictionary

Comment: `@staticmethod` has to be inside a class.

Comment: Then you call it with `className.getConfig(env)` or `classInstance.getConfig(env)`

Comment: That means that either `self.config` or `self.config["data-validation"]` is a list, not a dictionary.

Comment: Yes, that's what it means. And the problem is that it's being used to index a tuple, not a dictionary.

Comment: How are you setting `self.config`? Did you use `self.config = self.getConfig(env)`? My answer makes `getConfig()` return a tuple -- `self.config[0]` comes from `dataset2.json`, `self.config[1]` is from `dataset1.json`.

Comment: And if you're using the version of `getConfig()` from my answer, it returns 2 configurations. You need to index them. Did you want them to be merged in some way?