# caching python class instances

Tags: python, caching, singleton, multiple-instances, object-pooling

I have a memory heavy class, say a type representing a high-resolution resource (ie: media, models, data, etc), that can be instantiated multiple times with identical parameters, such as same filename of the resource loaded multiple times.

I'd like to implement some sort of unbounded `caching` on object creation to memory reuse identical instances if they have the same constructor parameter values. I don't care about mutability of one instance affecting the other shared ones. What is the easiest pythonic way to achieve this?

Note that neither `singletons`, `object-pools`, `factory methods` or field `properties` meet my use case.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a factory function with [functools.cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache):

```
import functools

@functools.cache
def make_myclass(*args, **kwargs):
    return MyClass(*args, **kwargs)
```

EDIT: Apparently you can decorate your class directly to get the same effect:

```
@functools.cache
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a):
        print("Creating new instance")
        self.a = a

>>> Foo(1)
Creating new instance
<__main__.Foo object at 0x0000021D7D61FFA0>
>>> Foo(1)
<__main__.Foo object at 0x0000021D7D61FFA0>
>>> Foo(2)
Creating new instance
<__main__.Foo object at 0x0000021D7D61F250>
```

Note the same memory address both times `Foo(1)` is called.

Edit 2: After some playing around, you can get your default-respecting instance cache behavior if you override `__new__` and do all of your caching and instantiation there:

```
class Foo:
    _cached = {}
    
    def __new__(cls, a, b=3):
        attrs = a, b
        if attrs in cls._cached:
            return cls._cached[attrs]
            
        print(f"Creating new instance Foo({a}, {b})")

        new_foo = super().__new__(cls)
        new_foo.a = a
        new_foo.b = b
        cls._cached[attrs] = new_foo  
        return new_foo
     
a = Foo(1)
b = Foo(1, 3)
c = Foo(b=3, a=1)
d = Foo(4)

print(a is b)
print(b is c)
print(c is d)
```

output:

```
Creating new instance Foo(1, 3)
Creating new instance Foo(4, 3)
True
True
False
```

The `__init__` will still be called after `__new__`, so you will want to do your expensive initialization (or all of it) in `__new__` after the cache check.

Comment: I constrained the question a bit, but otherwise this does it neatly! Is there a way to cache the class or constructor? or invoke the factory within the class creation? Cannot use public factory methods as their usage cannot be enforced in the call sites.

Comment: Updated with class decorator solution

Comment: Nice! Would you know how make this solution give the same instance when the class declares default arguments in the constructor such that `id(Foo()) ==  id(Foo(a=default))`?

Comment: That's a good question, this solution doesn't work with default args. Not sure about that right now, but I can mess around with it!

Comment: Updated again with solution for default arguments.

Comment: this works, but keep in mind that by wrapping the class in this cache object, certain things such as `@staticmethod` won't work properly within it if `python < 3.10`. see here: [error you get](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41921255), then [solution added](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/87848)

Comment: Things such as `isinstance`, `issubclass`, inheritance in general, anything that accesses the class (not the object) attributes, etc., will not work either.

Answer (score 0):

The decorator in the answer above will break inheritance, `isinstance`, `issubclass`, and will not work with `dataclasses`. The following is a better alternative that does not suffer from these shortcomings:

```py
import functools
from dataclasses import is_dataclass


def cached_class(cls):
    @functools.wraps(cls.__new__)
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return cls.__cache__(cls, args, tuple(kwargs.items()))

    @functools.cache
    def __cache__(cls, args, kwargs):
        if is_dataclass(cls):
            it = object.__new__(cls)
        else:
            it = cls.__orig_new__(cls, *args, **dict(kwargs))
        return it

    cls.__cache__ = __cache__
    cls.__orig_new__ = cls.__new__
    cls.__new__ = __new__
    return cls
```

Use as:

```py
@cached_class
class Foo:
   ...


>>> x = Foo()
>>> y = Foo()
>>> x is y
True
```