# Understanding the functionality of @staticmethod and @classmethod decorators in Python

Tags: python, oop

How does `@staticmethod` and `@classmethod` decorator works under the hood in Python?

I read that decorators are functions which takes a function as a parameter and returns a function back. They can be used for adding/wrapping functionality around another function.
I wanted to ask how `@staticmethod` and `@classmethod` works under the hood as a decorator?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685232/how-are-methods-classmethod-and-staticmethod-implemented-in-python